# Seconds delay on button click not working on Google Chrome

Tags: jquery

This is not working on Google-Chrome, but on Firefox it works.
it does disable the button on click but the login form is not posting and on Firefox I am able to login but not working on Chrome, click is disabled but can't login for some reason, removing this script fixes the problem.

```
var fewSeconds = 10;
    $('#btnLogin').click(function () {
        var btn = $(this);
        btn.prop('disabled', true);
        setTimeout(function () {
        btn.prop('disabled', false);
    }, fewSeconds * 1000);
});
```

**The script below is causing the same problem, still unable to login, button click is disabled but the post is not happening**

```
var fewSeconds = 10;
$('#btnLogin').click(function () {
    $('#btnLogin').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    setTimeout(function () {
    $('#btnLogin').attr('disabled', '');
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? Post a [mcve] please. [A simplified version of your code works](https://jsfiddle.net/t3zszqha/), so you'll need to post the code that doesn't.

Comment: Its working perfectly on my chrome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery .prop("disabled", false) not working in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240439/jquery-propdisabled-false-not-working-in-chrome)

Comment: it does disable the button click but, the form is not posting, I have this on login page and on firefox I am able to login but not on Chrome, click is disabled but can't login for some reason.

Comment: You still need to post a [mcve] as the code you posted so far doesn't have any issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find any solution online, so I tried this script instead and it worked for me and I hope it might help someone too:

```
$('#btnLogin').click(function () {
    $('#btnLogin').hide();
    $('#btnWait').show();
    setTimeout("$('#btnWait').hide();", 10000);
    setTimeout("$('#btnLogin').show();", 10000);
});
```